# Synchronize JQuery Animations with Calculation Within A Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, animation

I'm trying to make a script that run an animation while running a program, and I want to both to be synchronized. 
(It's much clearer inside the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vhutama/Y8zNQ/5/). I'm using JQuery and JQueryUI library.

The code is:

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log("log " + i);
    $("#textplaceholder").append(i + " ");
    $("#myDiv>div:eq(" + i + ")").delay( 1000 * i).effect("highlight", {color: 'lightblue'}, 1000);
}
});
```

**HTML**

```
       <body>
         <div id='myDiv'>
           <div class='ui-state-default'>Lorem</div>
           <div class='ui-state-default'>Ipsum</div>
           <div class='ui-state-default'>Dolor</div>
           <div class='ui-state-default'>Sit</div>
           <div class='ui-state-default'>Amet</div>
         </div>
         <div id='textplaceholder'>Looping for : </div>
       </body>
```

I made a loop which run codes used for calculation -- just a **console.log()** and an **.append()** in this example -- and codes for animation. The problem is, I want both to be synchronized in every iteration, so for example while my animation is on 3rd index, the code should not log/append more than 3. Any suggestion? I have tried the recursive solutions from other answers here, but somehow It doesn't work on **.animate()** and **.effect**, though I'm a beginner in JQuery, so maybe I could be wrong.

While searching, I found about http://api.jquery.com/promise/. Is this function capable to solve my problem? If so, can anyone provide a quick explanation about it?

P.S. I'm not a native English speaker, so sorry if I made wrong wordings or bad explanations.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a delay, you should use a setTimeout to execute everything in same time, and then synchronize.

http://jsfiddle.net/FJWL4/

```
$(function() {
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("log " + j);
            $("#textplaceholder").append(j + " ");
            $("#myDiv>div:eq(" + j + ")").effect("highlight", {color: 'lightblue'}, 1000);
            j++;
        }, 1000 * i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.